# Return a list with next high temperature from a list

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a list input: [70,71,74,69,70,76,71,80,70,65]
which represents the temperatures of the day, I am supposed to return a list which indicates the number of future days that are hotter than the present day. If there no hotter days than the present-day just add 0 to the list.

For the above input, the expected output is [ 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0]

To clarify the necessary work:
We search the position of the next higher temperature. If there is no higher one then return zero. e.g. Index0 is 70. The next temperatur after 70 is higher (71). So we write a 1. 71 is followed by 74 so we write 1 again. 74 is followed by 69 and 70 which are lower but 76 is higher. So we write a 3. And so on ...

One approach I can think of is using two for loops and finding the next higher value.

```
        List<Integer> result =  new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(size,0));
        for(int i = 0; i<list.size();i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<list.size();j++){
                if(list.get(i)<list.get(j)){
                    result.add(i,j-i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

The time complexity of the above approach is O(n^2). I would like to know is there any other method with better Time complexity?

Comment: The expected output doesn't match the problem description.  The first value should be 5.

Comment: *which indicates the number of future days that are hotter than the present day.* - I am confused about your output as there are 5 days hotter than day[0]

Comment: What is present day? Everyone seems to assume present day is the first one in the list... is it?

Comment: Ah I think I see it. Present day as in which one in the loop one is on. So for each one you need to count how many there are hotter than the one you're on. Index 0, 5 hotter than it in the whole list, Index 2, 3 hotter than it, etc. But then this doesn't add up with the expected output. The code sample seems to do a less than comparison too. So, let me ask: Define 'hotter'.

Comment: I determined his needs and edited his informations:

To clarify the necessary work: We search the position of the next higher temperature. If there is no higher one then return zero. e.g. Index0 is 70. The next temperatur after 70 is higher (71). So we write a 1. 71 is followed by 74 so we write 1 again. 74 is followed by 69 and 70 which are lower but 76 is higher. So we write a 3. And so on ...

Comment: I believe you want to use `result.set(i,j-i)` and not `result.add(i,j-i)`  The latter grows the size of the result list which is not what you want.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The next immediate hotter day should be listed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you meant you want to know the distance between each element and the next strictly greater element, since this matches your expected output.

Simply use a stack, first push the very first element into the stack, then start iterating on your array from the second element, check if the current element is greater than the top element in the stack. If it's greater then the current index is the answer for the top element in the stack, update its answer and pop it, then repeat for the new top element in the stack. Repeat this until the stack is empty or the current element is not greater than the stack top element. After that push the current element to the stack too so that we can find its answer and continue iterating.

The complexity of this method is O(n).

Here's a code I found at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-greater-element/, it's slightly modified to meet your exact needs:

```
//Java program to print next 
//greater element using stack 

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class NGE
{
    static class stack
    {
        int top;
        int items[] = new int[100];

        // Stack functions to be used by printNGE
        void push(int x)
        {
            if (top == 99)
            {
                System.out.println("Stack full");
            }
            else
            {
                items[++top] = x;
            }
        }

        int pop()
        {
            if (top == -1)
            {
                System.out.println("Underflow error");
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                int element = items[top];
                top--;
                return element;
            }
        }

        boolean isEmpty()
        {
            return (top == -1) ? true : false;
        }
    }

    /* prints element and NGE pair for
    all elements of arr[] of size n */
    static void printNGE(int arr[], int n)
    {
        int i = 0;
        stack s = new stack();
        s.top = -1;
        int element, next;

        //answer initialized with zeros
        ArrayList<Integer> answer = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(n, 0));

        /* push the first element to stack */
        s.push(0);

        // iterate for rest of the elements
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            next = i;

            if (s.isEmpty() == false)
            {

                // if stack is not empty, then
                // pop an element from stack
                element = s.pop();

                /* If the popped element is smaller than 
                next, then a) print the pair b) keep 
                popping while elements are smaller and 
                stack is not empty */
                while (arr[element] < arr[next])
                {
                    answer.set(element, next - element);
                    if (s.isEmpty() == true)
                        break;
                    element = s.pop();
                }

                /* If element is greater than next, then 
                push the element back */
                if (arr[element] > arr[next])
                    s.push(element);
            }

            /* push next to stack so that we can find next 
            greater for it */
            s.push(next);
        }

        System.out.println(answer);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int arr[] = { 70, 71, 74, 69, 70, 76, 71, 80, 70, 65 };
        int n = arr.length;
        printNGE(arr, n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Moustafa for the comment. It is really helpful and solved the above-posted problem. We are supposed to use the list indices in the stack(if we use the temperature values retrieving them would result in the incorrect answer as there are duplicate elements in the given list).

Comment: I tried to upvote your answer, it's working as I am a newbie here. I should have posted the question in a better way using the keyword Next greater Element(NGE).

Comment: @Oskar You're welcome ;). And yes indeed using the values instead of the indices would result in a wrong answer because there are duplicates. Upvoting isn't allowed until you've 15+ reputation, but you can accept my answer by clicking on the check mark symbol underneath the voting buttons.

Comment: gotcha ya! I had this question in an interview, gave the O(n^2) solution. I also found a similar problem on leetcode